# find all procs of a namespace in Tcl

Tags: namespaces, tcl, introspection, proc

let us say that I have a namespace. I want to find all of the namespace procs.
For example,
let us say that I have this code:

```
namespace eval foo { 
   proc me {} { puts "yey!" }
   proc moo {} { puts "ney!" }
}
puts [ getAllNamespaceProcs foo ] ; # getAllNamespaceProcs is what I do not know how to do
```

This should yield:

```
> { me moo }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `info procs` command can be told what namespace to look in:

```
info procs ::foo::*
```

This will yield `::foo::me ::foo::moo` (or the other way round; `lsort` it if you care) and you can filter that (e.g., with `lmap` and `namespace tail`) if you want to get the result that you mention.

Comment: To wit: `lmap procname [info procs ::foo::*] {namespace tail $procname}`.